# Rather than model, get value of cellrenderer in a GtkTreeView

Tags: python, pygtk, gtktreeview, cellrenderer

For set data to the treeview, I'm using the `set_cell_data_func` at some columns.
source like this:

```
myRenderer = gtk.CellRendererText()
column = gtk.TreeViewColumn("col1", myRenderer, text=columnId)
column.set_cell_data_func(myRenderer, func1)

def func1(self, column, cell, model, iter):
    cell_name = model.get_value(iter, 0)
    if cell_name in category_dict:
        cell.set_property('text', category_dict[cell_name])
    else:
        cell.set_property('text', "")
    return
```

Therefore, my tree_view_model doesn't have a data that is displayed in the treeview.
How to retrieve the data that has been set in set_cell_data_func,
Do you have any?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  What are you trying to retrieve?

Comment: Also, func1 shouldn't have a self argument, since it is a static function, not a method.

Comment: thanx lxop for responce.  you are right, i'm using func1 inside of class...  func1 is doing some calculate, display results.  I'd like to get value of this results, from cellrendere's property "text". thanx!

Answer (score 1):

Use `cell.get_property ("text")`